# Powershell WPF Navigation bar Create ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: wpf, powershell

When I hover over the icon in the navigation bar I need to create a message (like the 'Safely Remove Hardware..' of the USB icon) 'Click here to Exit'. This what I use to create the icon:

```
.
.
$notifyIcon.Icon = $icon 
$notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon  = "Info" 
$notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Powershell Search"
$notifyIcon.BalloonTipText  = "Loading Search GUI. Please wait ..."
$notifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(50)
#Create mouse hover box here.
$notifyIcon.add_Click({                         
    $notifyIcon.Visible = $false
    $form.Close()
    Stop-Process $pid
})
```

I know I can use Add-MouseEnter, but I do not want a ToolTip message here.

Answer (score 0):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
$text = 'This is just a text'
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = $text
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Tip Title"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000)
```

This will suffice your need I believe

Comment: Unfortunately not. It just gives a permanent Tootip. I need something responding to MouseHover.

Comment: OO. Alright. Let me check something for the mouseover events.. so that we would be able to trigger that on that event..

Comment: I can get a ContextMenu item up if I right-click. All I need is something similar from MouseEnter.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you :

```
$objNotifyIcon.Text = "when hover appear"
```

Comment: I can now answer this myself: The Text property is the one needed:
      `$notifyIcon.add_MouseMove({
           $notifyIcon.Text = "Click to Exit"
       })`